# "constructing proofs directly by hand" or "directly constructing proofs by hand"

Tags: grammar, expressions, academia

There are two alternatives for a sentence

> Nevertheless, developing automatically verifiable proofs by proof assistants usually takes more time than constructing proofs directly by hand.

and

> Nevertheless, developing automatically verifiable proofs by proof assistants usually takes more time than directly constructing proofs by hand.

Someone told me that "constructing proofs directly by hand" was better than the other representation, but I can not understand the reason.

Much appreciation to anyone who would like to give me some help!

Comment: Yes; I agree with your advisor. The words of the string 'directly by hand' sit well together, and this variant feels less staccato, more fluent. This is perhaps because the two adverbials are quite closely related semantically. _But grammatically, both are acceptable._

Comment: Thanks for your kindness! @EdwinAshworth

Comment: Both choices are unclear. Is "by hand" a metaphor, or are you speaking of actual hand labor? And whose hand is involved? Also, how does one "construct" a proof? This is a metaphor but its parameters are not spelled out -- does one assemble pre-constructed pieces or does one start from scratch and build the logic chain? Before you worry about optional placement of adverbs, you might think about what you want to say and imply.

Comment: The are both correct, but the emphasis is simply in different places. What aspect do you want to call out as being direct? The overall construction or the "handedness" of the construction? What does *directly* actually mean?

Comment: @JasonBassford ITPs are softwares that enable people to construct proofs as computer programs. I want to explain that the construction is done by writing in the paper but not using a computer. I think I want to emphasize the "handedness" of the construction. Therefore, it may be better to use "constructing proofs directly by hand" because this sentence indicates the proof is done by written in papers.  Meanwhile, after reading the explanation of John Lawler, I found my sentence is unclear. Thank you most sincerely!